# Communication between java server and android client

Tags: android

I have built a java server app and am trying to get my android app to communicate with it. After reading [Android Client Server communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150779/android-client-server-communication) I tried the socket example. However I have run into a wall because on the server side I can return an array of my object but on the client side I'm not able to retrieve it since buffereader takes a string only
Server code

```
public List<Person> processInput(String theInput) {
    String peopleOutput = null;
        List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();



    if (state == WAITING) {
               SqliteDBhelper db = new SqliteDBhelper();
                people = db.getPeople();
return people;
```

Client code

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
List<Person> fromServer;
String fromUser;

while ((fromServer = in.readLine()) != null) {
  List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
  Person person = new Person();
  people = fromServer;
```

So from the looks of it I cannot pass an object via this socket method. Will the json do what I need? I just dont want to spend another day coding somthing that won't work for me. All I'm trying to do is have a db that my server has access to, the server reads the db and returns the table data in the form of my objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the client your reading not from the socket but from the standard input. But you should read from the socket instead:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Comment: this is the tutorial i was working from.  in this example it reads from the standard input.  but thank you.  ill have to research this further.

Comment: Yes but only to get user input that is sent to the outputstream of the socket.

Comment: yes thank you.  here is a good example for anyone else that might need it: http://www.coderanch.com/t/205325/sockets/java/send-any-java-Object-through