# How to "send" a variable from app to a different module?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I had an original stand alone java code, that could be used by multiple computers in order to find the answer in a distributed systems fashion. Alternatively, I could run everything I needed in eclipse by running a few projects at the same time, instead of one component in each computer.

Now I want to extend this project in Android Studio. The basic idea is that the user gives some input in the app and then ,after some processing, some output comes back.

I have tried using modules (since I cannot separate the different components with projects) and I have not been able to replicate my result.

My questions are :

- Can different modules in Android Studio be run simultaneously, like
  different projects in eclipse ? If not how can I find a solution ?
- If yes, how can I make the modules and the app communicate between each other? e.g. I have an EditText, which I save it as a String variable. How can I send it to a different module for it to be processed or passed on to different modules ?

Comment: This might be helpful to you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @GlenPierce. I might have not been clear in my question, but I don't want to use intents. My components are stand-alone java files that run in eclipse. I wish my app to able to communicate with them somehow.

Comment: Do you run this as an Android app? When you run a module on the phone, it is packaged into a apk file together with all the modules it depends on (and any other dependencies). So during runtime there is no concept of 'modules'. You may have to rethink the definition of projects/modules, or maybe I just don't understand correctly. But if one module depends on an other it can just call it's java methods and communicate however you like. Key here is the gradle configuration to setup dependencies right. [Documentation link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html)

Comment: Thank you @RobCo. Yes, I run an android app. Can I somehow run modules on their own first? The idea is to take a variable from MainActivity.java and use it in a java file in another module. In order to do this will I have to configure the dependencies ? If so how?

Comment: So are you trying to communicate with a client-server architecture?

Comment: @Thecave3 I read up on client-server architecture, and it sounds very similar to what I am doing, so probably yes.

Comment: Ok, I'm writing an answer

Comment: please post your code try.

Answer (score -1):

To the discussion in the comments seems you want to pass data from your computer (or a  computer that I'll call server from now) to your Android app (that from now I'll call client).

What you are trying to achieve so is the client-server architecture (standard use):

1. client make a request of some data of the server
2. server sends data to client
3. client process data or show data to user

The decision about how the communication should be it's up to you. There are many possibilities (web-socket, custom API REST), but it's up to you and your capabilities.

Is it really hard to explain in just one answer the whole process from the code view, so I link [here](http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-client-implementation/) for the client part.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150779/android-client-server-communication) question could really help you.